# Postgresql Insert into table using select statement by for loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a establishment master table with 25 rows. I have another person table with 1500 records which belongs to one of the establishment. I want to insert into person table the same 1500 records for all the other 24 establishment.

How can I do that?

In oracle it is very simple in the following ways

```
for loop (select est_code from estableishment where est_code <> 100) 
loop 
   insert into person(...) 
   select .. from person where est_code <> 100 
end loop; 
end;
```

but it didn't work in Postgres.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  You don't need to actually show us 1500 (or even 25) records to get your point across.

Comment: No loop required (neither in Oracle, nor in Postgres): `insert into some_table (col1, col2, ...) select col1, col2, ... from other_table where est_code <> 100;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a loop or cursor for this in any database.  You can just do:

```
insert into person (. . ., est_code) 
    select . . ., e.est_code 
    from person p cross join
         establishment e
    where e.est_code <> 100 and
          p.est_code = 100; -- I think these are the ones you actually want
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.